# User having execute procedure permission in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, users

Dears,
Greetings,

How can I create a new user in Microsoft SQL Database, so that user must have only execute permission on only 1 procedure in one of Ms SQL Database.

Regards,
Salahuddin.

Comment: Access management is really well documented on microsoft website.
If you are experimenting issue with a specific case, please add more detail about the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

Create new user, SQL or Windows auth you need to decide:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-database-user?view=sql-server-ver15

Execute permission to one object:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/grant-permissions-on-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15